# why doesn't summary(tibble()) report NA's in chr columns?

Tags: r, tibble

I was doing some data cleaning on data stored in a tibble and ended up repeatedly confusing myself by converting some empty string observations into `NA` and then having the observations seemingly disappear when I called `summary(df)` to check my work. It appears that when working with a `tibble()` `NA`'s are only reported for non-character columns. Why is this? Is it intentional? If so why?

Minimal example:

```r
tdf <- tibble::tibble(a = c("apple", "pear", NA), 
                      b = 1:3, c = factor(letters[1:3]))
# We see that the NA in the 'chr' column is not displayed
summary(tdf) 
#>       a                   b       c    
#>  Length:3           Min.   :1.0   a:1  
#>  Class :character   1st Qu.:1.5   b:1  
#>  Mode  :character   Median :2.0   c:1  
#>                     Mean   :2.0        
#>                     3rd Qu.:2.5        
#>                     Max.   :3.0
# But NA in other column types will be
tdf[3, 2:3] <- NA
summary(tdf)
#>       a                   b           c    
#>  Length:3           Min.   :1.00   a   :1  
#>  Class :character   1st Qu.:1.25   b   :1  
#>  Mode  :character   Median :1.50   c   :0  
#>                     Mean   :1.50   NA's:1  
#>                     3rd Qu.:1.75           
#>                     Max.   :2.00           
#>                     NA's   :1

# This behavior is not the same with data.frame
ddf <- data.frame(a = c("apple", "pear", NA), 
                  b = 1:3, c = factor(letters[1:3]))
summary(ddf)
#>      a           b       c    
#>  apple:1   Min.   :1.0   a:1  
#>  pear :1   1st Qu.:1.5   b:1  
#>  NA's :1   Median :2.0   c:1  
#>            Mean   :2.0        
#>            3rd Qu.:2.5        
#>            Max.   :3.0
ddf[3, 2:3] <- NA
summary(ddf)
#>      a           b           c    
#>  apple:1   Min.   :1.00   a   :1  
#>  pear :1   1st Qu.:1.25   b   :1  
#>  NA's :1   Median :1.50   c   :0  
#>            Mean   :1.50   NA's:1  
#>            3rd Qu.:1.75           
#>            Max.   :2.00           
#>            NA's   :1
```

Created on 2018-03-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: `tdf %>% group_by(a) %>% tally` will give you the count of the `NA`s

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you create the column 'a' in your data.frame they are defined as factors (see stringsAsFactors). When you create the column in your tibble it is a character type column.

```
class(ddf$a)
"factor"

class(tdf$a)
"character"
```

If you create your data.frame with stringsAsFactors = FALSE, you will see that it will behave like a tibble.

```
ddf <- data.frame(a = c("apple", "pear", NA), 
              b = 1:3, c = factor(letters[1:3]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

class(ddf$a)
"character"
```

Comment: well it does explain the discrepancy, while showing that `summary` never reveals the number of NA's in a character column no matter the data structure, which is good to know -- so i'm upvoting. i'd still like to know why `summary()` does report this: e.g. if I call `sum(is.na(ddf$a))` I get the number of `NA` in any character vector.

Comment: When you call is.na() it returns TRUE or FALSE. TRUE is 1 and FALSE is 0 in numeric. Therefore the sum will be how many TRUEs are in the vector. Try: `as.numeric(TRUE)` and `as.numeric(FALSE)`.

Comment: yeah that's my point obviously, e.g. `sapply(df, function(x){sum(is.na(x))})` will tell me how many `NA` are in each column of the whole data.frame or tibble. the point is not "how to count NA" (which is easy) the point is why doesn't summary report the `NA` in a character vector

Comment: Summary reports the number of `NA` in a factor vector because NA is another level of the vector. You can see that it also reports the number of pear and apple. It can be seen that NAs are reported as `NA's` which I imagine it was coded like this since it is not dependent on the levels that one uses. In the character type vector this "feature" was not implemented. Why not? I do not know that.

Comment: I don't think `NA` is a level of the factor. e.g. `c <- factor(c("a", "b", NA)); levels(c)` returns "a" and "b" only.

Comment: You are completely right. I did the mistake of writing `"NA"` instead of `NA` . I guess that it might be related to the mode. `mode(tdf$a)` is character while `mode(ddf$a)` is numeric.

Answer (score 1):

**Why?**
Probably a design choice.

**How to work around it:**
You can use `lapply`and `table()` whith the parameter `useNA= "always"` or `"ifany"`:

```
tdf <- tibble::tibble(a = c("apple", "pear", NA, NA), 
                      b = 1:4, c = factor(letters[1:4]), 
                      d = c("apple", "pear", "peach", NA))
lapply(tdf, function(x){table(x, useNA = "always")})
# $a
# x
# apple  pear  <NA> 
#     1     1     2 
# $b
# x
#   1    2    3    4 <NA> 
#   1    1    1    1    0 
# $c
# x
#   a    b    c    d <NA> 
#   1    1    1    1    0 
# $d
# x
# apple peach  pear  <NA> 
#     1     1     1     1
```

You can also check single columns with `dplyr::tally` after grouping

```
tdf %>% group_by(a) %>% tally
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#       a     n
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 apple     1
# 2  pear     1
# 3  <NA>     2
```

Comment: i appreciate you taking the time, but my question is about the why not the how

Comment: I know. However, wanted to include it for future visitors.